# Modify @OneToMany entity in Spring Data Rest without its repository

Tags: java, rest, spring-data-rest, json-patch

In my project I use object of type *A* which has OneToMany relation (orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) to objects of type *B*. I need SpringDataRest (SDR) to store complete full *A* object with its *B* objects (children) using single one POST request. I tried several combinations in SDR, the only one which worked for me, was to create @RepositoryRestResource for object *A* and to create @RepositoryRestResource also for object *B*, but mark this (*B*) as exported=false (if I did not create repository out of object *B* at all, it would not work -> just *A* object would be stored on single POST request, but not its children (@OneToMany relation) of type *B*; the same outcome occurs if exported=false is omitted for *B* repository).
 Is this ok and the only way how to achieve it (single POST request with storing all objects at once)?

The reason I'm asking, in my previous example, I have to (I would like to) control all objects "lifecycle" by using *A*'s repository. I am ok with it, because *A*->*B* relation is composition (*B* does not exists outside of *A*). But I have serious problem of editing (also removing) one certain object of type *B* by SDR using its parent repository (since object *B* doest not have its own repository exported). Maybe, this is not possible by definition. I have tried these solutions:

- PATCH for "/A/1/B/2" does not work -> method not allowed (in headers
  is "Allow: GET, DELETE") -> so, also PUT is out of question
- Json Patch would not work either - PATCH for "/A/1" using json patch
  content-type [{"op": "add", "path": "/B/2", ....}] -> "no such index
  in target array" - because Json Patch uses scalar "2" after "array"
  as a index to its array. This is not practical in Java world, when
  relations are kept in Set of objects - indexing has no meaning
  at all.
- I could export repository (exported=true) of object *B* for
  manipulating it "directly", but this way I would loose ability to
  store the whole object *A* with its *B* objects at one single POST
  request as I have mentioned before.

I would like to avoid sending the whole *A* object with one single tiny   modification of its *B* object for PUT, if possible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to change the child entity as follows. As a sample I used the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class One {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL)
    private List<Many> manies = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Many {

    public Many(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

I just have a repository for `One` exposed.

(My examples use the excellent [httpie - CLI HTTP client](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie))

**Removing an item using json patch**

This example will remove the second item in the manies list. You could use @OrderColumn to make sure that you can rely on the order of list items.

```
echo '[{"op":"remove", "path":"/manies/1"}]' | http PATCH :8080/ones/1 Content-Type:application/json-patch+json -v

PATCH /ones/1 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
    {
        "op": "remove", 
        "path": "/manies/1"
    }
]
```

**Replacing the entire list using json patch**

This sample replaces the list with the array specified in the value.

```
echo '[{"op":"add", "path":"/manies", "value":[{"name":"3"}]}]' | http PATCH :8080/ones/1 Content-Type:application/json-patch+json -v

PATCH /ones/1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
    {
        "op": "add", 
        "path": "/manies", 
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Adding an item to the list using json patch**

This sample adds an item to the end of a list. Also here the client just needs to know the length of the list before the update. So the order does not really matter here.

```
echo '[{"op":"add", "path":"/manies/-", "value":{"name":"4"}}]' | http PATCH :8080/ones/1 Content-Type:application/json-patch+json -v

PATCH /ones/1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
    {
        "op": "add", 
        "path": "/manies/-", 
        "value": {
            "name": "4"
        }
    }
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mathias, for your comprehensive post. My problem is, like I mentioned, that I use Sets and not Lists (@OrderColumn does not work with Set). Let me ask you a personal question: don't you think, that using "index" instead of "id" of real entity with easy rest query is quite "strange" solution? I know, this comes with JsonPatch main purpose (to modify json)... but anyway, I am curious, if this can be done in different way.

Comment: I am trying out your solution for adding an item to the list and I am receiving several errors: doing`"op": "add", "path": "/manies/-", "value":{"name":"4"}`to a list that has no entries gives me `o.s.e.s.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method size() cannot be found on One type`, so I tried using `/manies`, which gave me `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.patch.PatchException: Could not read {"name":"4"} into class org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag!` Any ideas?