# How to manage a one to many entity using JPA and Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, repository-pattern, spring-data-rest

This question is probably related to this SO Link "[POSTing a @OneToMany sub-resource association in Spring Data REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311978/posting-a-onetomany-sub-resource-association-in-spring-data-rest)"

I would like to understand how to do "Post" has many "Comments" idea using a single PostRepository that is exposed using SDR.

How will i add more comments to the existing posts?

The question is when i do not have a CommentRepository, i will not have any "Location url" to send to the Request.

In this case how should i send the new comment or modify an existing comment?
Note: CURL command or HAL Browser usage for performing the same will be useful to understand how it works

Comment: Ok, there should be no problem simple putting/patching the whole posting itself (including the list of comments) but updating a single comment without a comment repository? Don't know about that.

Comment: Can you provide your entity mapping and the repositories that are in play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question - so you might want to look at this one. I tried to explain the different use cases there in detail.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34864254/5371736

Does that apply to your usecase

Comment: Your answer  to the similar question shed a lot of light on my problem statement.  However, with the annotation as described the relationship between One and Many is really more like a "many to many" relationship.
The solution you have highlighted gave me a good insight into JSON PATCH, I will try to check if the same approach works for that also.

Comment: The "one to many" and "many to many" was just how i was doing the mapping.  This does answer my question. Tks!